# Как программно сменить рингтон на Android 4.0+?

Tags: android, аудио

Имеется путь к файлу, который надо с BrоadcastReceiver-а поставить на звонок. Нормального, понятного ответа так и не нашел. Кто может предложить рабочий вариант? Лучше всего - метод, куда передал полный путь к файлу и имя файла, и в нем произвелась вся грязная работа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не помогает?

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                ringtoneUri);
```

`ringtoneUri` - URI ссылка на файл со звуком

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL file:***...

Comment: Ну извините, значит неверно сгенерировали Uri файла. [Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) вообще то отличается от обычного пути файла - вы знаете об этом?

Comment: Ну извините, но я использовал Uribe.fromFile(myFile); и ожидал, что сработает

Comment: Пробуйте получить URI через какие-то стандартные механизмы. Например, MediaStore.

Comment: @Izobara, лог дайте в студию с `Unknown URL file`

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, а для успешного выполнения( без срабатвания программных исключений ) разве не требуется разрешение:

     android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, в общем, там нужен был необычный формат Uri. Совершенно случайно обнаружил.

Answer (score 0):

```
File ringFile = new File(dir, newRing);
String filepath = ringFile.getAbsolutePath();
File ringtoneFile = new File(filepath);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Ringtone");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, " ");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 215454);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
mContext.getContentResolver().delete(uri,MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
Uri newUri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
try {
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(mContext, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    System.err.println("Can't set ringtone");
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Такое вот решение. Необычный тип uri.